# How could I auto-keyframe a value which is not a transform? EI. Using a value slider in real-time

Tags: animation, keyframes, custom-properties

For context, I am rigging a Dalek, and want to be able to turn the top lights on and off in real time when making animations. I have figured out how to make custom properties work with auto-keying, however this only works when you release the slider, to save that value. A workaround I have found, is to make the slider a bool on/off tick box instead, so it saves every time I click it, but I would then need to smooth the keyframes afterwards so the lights don't instantly turn on and off, but with a bool, it won't let me do that.

Is there another way I can do this - control a slider in real time in an animation?